# Parallel automation in Selenium

Tags: performance, selenium, parallel-processing, automation

I am new to Selenium.

My doubt is,

After submitting credential form during automation (login), is it possible to create multiple driver instance, and have multiple browser windows and run events parallely in different threads, by injecting sessions/cookies to increase performance. I learned its not possible to work on different tabs parallely.
My main concern is regarding the time consumption. Would it cost have multiple driver instances?

Thanks in advance.
Happy coding :)

Comment: I have a write up on how to do exactly this with Test Junkie, the only thing its missing which you need is loading cookies. Check it out here https://www.test-junkie.com/tutorials/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.

Try to use selenium grid [documentation can be found here](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/) in order to parallelization

It allows to run tests in parallel on multiple machines

I recommend to use it with docker if you are going to work on a local environment

You can found more info here [Selenium docker github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)

Regarding your question, its better to work on different browser instances than trying to work on different tabs.

The only cost will be the infrastructure cost, you can use testing frameworks in python like pytest to parallelize your test execution against selenium grid

Comment: In my experience Selenium Grid has been very flaky and I have seen ~30% increased test failure rate when I used it back in the day. You are much better of writing your own producer/consumer model using a message broker like RabbitMQ.